# How to stop sending requests when request number reaches desired value

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a jmeter script that simulates sending 5 requests / second for 10 users for 5 minutes. I want to stop sending requests when the request number reaches 15 000. I want to be sure that EXACT 15000 requests have been sent and send not more not less. What's the best and simplest way to achieve this ?